# Prevent spawned robot model from moving

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
I want to control the robot model that I spawned using spawn_model script, but after spawning it starts to rotate slightly, and I think this causes problems with Moveit package, because when I try to execute planned path I get this error:

```
[ERROR] [1507023800.853643333, 2796.811000000]: 
Invalid Trajectory: start point deviates from current robot state more than 0.01
joint 'Kuka_kr3__base_revolute': expected: -0.441804, current: -0.420193
```

[GIF](https://gfycat.com/gifs/detail/UncomfortablePepperyAntarcticgiantpetrel)

How can I stop such movement?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17380/prevent-spawned-robot-model-from-moving/) by [Fiddle](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3737/fiddle/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 35 on 2017-10-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wentz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2629/wentz/) on 2017-10-05**:
It might be a problem with the controller you are using in the simulation. I had a similar problem with the controller of a robot gripper that caused the gripper to move without giving any commands. Which controller are you using? Can you post the code of the UpdateChild() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The answer is to set damping and friction properties in URDF correctly

---

Originally posted by [Fiddle](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3737/fiddle/) with karma: 35 on 2017-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0